# BigQuery: Numeric DataType: Cannot store more that 19 digits

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, numeric, sqldatatypes

Why is that the column with NUMERIC dataType in BigQuery is unable to store this number: 12345678901234567890 [20 Digits].

The official documents say - it can store decimal values with 38 decimal digits of precision and 9 decimal digits of scale.

I've tried the following in a column which has NUMERIC dataType:

- 1234567890123456789 - this works.
- 12345678901234567890 - this fails.
- 12345678901234567890.0 - this works.

Is this a bug from bigQuery end? Will I have to needlessly apply ".0" for every number greater than 19 digits.

---

Link to official document:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

---

Screencap of error when I insert number with length 20 in column of dataType NUMERIC.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use just `12345678901234567890` BigQUery consider this as a INT64 data type thus an error

You need somehow to tell BQ engine that this is not an integer but rather float or numeric
The simplest way to do so is to use `12345678901234567890.0` - in this case BQ will treat this as FLOAT64. If you need make sure it is NUMERIC you can for example explicitly cast it `CAST(12345678901234567890.0 as NUMERIC)`

See also example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  12345678901234567890.0 float_value_a, 
  CAST(12345678901234567890.0 AS NUMERIC) numeric_value_b,
  CAST('12345678901234567890' AS NUMERIC) numeric_value_c, 
  CAST('12345678901234567890' AS FlOAT64) float_value_d
```

with result

```
Row float_value_a           numeric_value_b         numeric_value_c         float_value_d    
1   1.2345678901234567E19   12345678901234567890    12345678901234567890    1.2345678901234567E19
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This makes sense. I've one more weird observation - When I execute the Google dataflow pipeline which populates a BQ table - For numeric columns - 2019080604294580495071(example value) is for some reason converted to - 
2019080604294580500000. Dose this makes sense? I do not know what is at play here.

Comment: how you see that this is actually `2019080604294580500000`? usually this happens when you export your data to csv file and than open in excel. is it your case?

Comment: No, I'm reading messages from a Google pub/sub subscription and processing those to BigQuery table using Apache beam. The thing is - In the logs I can see the values processed to BigQuery is  2019080604294580495071 but when I query the same in the BiqQuery - the same value shows up to be 2019080604294580500000. Not at all sure what could be the reason. Every log before and after processing message looks correct.

Comment: Can you try passing it from Beam as a string instead? Maybe something is parsing it as a floating point number.